# Open Source CMS/static site generator for clients and developers

Tags: web-development, cms, static-site-generator

I have seen [huge lists](https://jamstack.org/generators/) of static site generators and also many, many CMS's with various feature sets. While I, as a developer, have personally use a few of these myself nearly all of them contain features meant for developers that could present a fairly steep learning curve to non-developer clients.

I have seen various different CMS offerings each with one or two of the features I am looking for, but never all at once, so I am wondering if there are any static site generators out there that have all of these features in one platform or service:

- WYSIWYG editing of site contents that isnt just blog posts (ideally inline/on the page, something kinda like webflow.com or respondcms.com, although i haven't used either of those enough to see of they work for my purpose)
- automatic commits to a git repository when changes are published (ive seen this in forestry.io and https://www.netlifycms.org/)
- allows for custom templates
- Ideally Open source if possible, if not free, if not somewhat cheap

something like metalsmith that has plugins that enable each of these things would also work for this, the point is i'm essentially looking for a WYSIWYG CMS or static site generator that allows me the developer have full control over the site's template while allowing clients edit the site's content and saving their changes to version control in a way that doesn't require them to understand what git is or how it works.

Comment: just discovered https://mavo.io, which was mentioned as the inline-editing software powering https://yax.com/. Plan to try it out soon and if it works i'll add this as an answer